# Callback for Google Places Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Is there a status callback for the [Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) (*specifically* ***Autocomplete***)?

There does not seem to be one for the client js lib, only for the Places Web Service. Seems a waste to *fake* another call to detect quota status.

```js
const options = {
  types: ['address'],
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'us'
  }
};

let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('test'), options);
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => console.log(autocomplete.getPlace()));
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=_REPLACE_API_KEY_HERE_&libraries=places"></script>
```